# How to make a secret key & padding? (AES-256)

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to learn about encryption (AES-256 specifically). I found a code I am looking at but I am trying to figure how it is working. This is the code(I didn't write this):

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad
from base64 import b64encode, b64decode

key = '/I02fMuSSvnouuu+/vyyD7NuSEVDB/0gte/z50dM0b4='
data = 'test'
cipher = AES.new(b64decode(key), AES.MODE_CBC)
padded_data = pad(data.encode(), cipher.block_size)

print(b64encode(padded_data))
```

Can someone explain whats going on here? First of all I am trying to figure out what the `key` does. If I understand it correctly its like a secret and you shouldn't give it out. How do you come up with your own key? I tried to input something random, but came up with an error saying its the incorrect **AES key length**. Lastly I want to know exactly what `padded_data` is doing. Is this what makes it encrypt?

Comment: The key has to be 256 bits (for AES *256*) long. Please note that it is Base64 encoded in the code and the **decoded** value needs to be 256 bits (=32 bytes) long.

Comment: Thanks Klaus for clearing it up a little bit! How do you make the actual key like that one that is in the code?

Comment: Have 32 bytes, any will do, should be (cryptographically) random. Encode them with base64. An encoding example is in your code.

Comment: I understand now! Thanks :)

Comment: Note that you would generally try and keep keys *out* of base 64 encoding or any kind of textual string, as those are difficult to destroy and easy to retrieve. Randomly creating them is one thing, storing them securely is another. Using system key stores would be one option. Base 64 is fine for *playing* with crypto (or storing test values) though :)

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info! @MaartenBodewes